# how I can find out, which compiler I have used

Tags: compiler-construction, gfortran, netcdf

I have installed  NetCDF "binary-netcdf-4.0.1_gfortran_gfortran_c++.tar ". But I am not sure about the gfortran compiler I have used. How can I find the compiler I have used?

Answer (score 2):

Run `gfortran -v` to tell you which version you have.

Comment: sumesh does not ask for the version of the currently available gfortran compiler but for the version of the gfortran compiler which was used to compile netCDF.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from netcdf 4.1, which uses [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config), you can do this:

```
$ nc-config  --all
```

This gives something like:

> ```
> This netCDF 4.1.1 has been built with the following features: 
>   --libs      -> -L/opt/local/lib -lnetcdf
>   --fc        -> openmpif77
>   --fflags    -> -O2 -m32 -I/opt/local/include
>   --flibs     -> -L/opt/local/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf
>   --has-f77   -> yes
>   --has-f90   -> yes
> ```

Comment: nc-config print out only the compiler name and not its version. sumesh does already know that the netCDF library was compiled with gfortran. The information he is looking for is not provided by `nc-config --all`.